# Ubuntu DHCP server doesn't assign a fixed address

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp, virtualbox-networking

I am an IT student, and I'm working with Ubuntu on VirtualBox. One of my virtual machines has a DHCP server installed, and it's set to give a specific IP-address (192.168.1.55) to a host Uclient. Uclient does get an IP address from my DHCP server, but it doesn't get that specific address (it gets 192.168.1.20 instead). I checked everything a hundred times, but it still doesn't work, so my only idea is that maybe I wrote something wrong in the config file? I'll attach the screenshot to this question, hope someone can help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2ULu.png

Edit: the text itself:

```
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
log-facility-local7;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.20 192.168.1.100;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
option domain-name "example.org";
option routers 192.168.1.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
default-lease-time 604800;
max-lease-time 604800;

host Uclient {
hardware Ethernet 00:01:08:a3:bb:c3;
fixed-address 192.168.1.55;
}
}
```

Comment: please copy and paste that text!

Comment: I'm not sure how to copy from VirtualBox, but I retyped it from my screenshot and added to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the common stuff out of the braces to be on its own. Do not include the static IP addresses, based on MAC, in your DHCP pool, and not inside the braces for the pool. so:

```
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
option domain-name "example.org";
option routers 192.168.1.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
log-facility-local7;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.20 192.168.54;
}

host Uclient {
  hardware Ethernet 00:01:08:a3:bb:c3;
  fixed-address 192.168.1.55;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I edited it, but it still doesn't work - Uclient keeps getting 192.168.1.20.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dXBUNkc.png  https://i.imgur.com/B3xrjfu.png

Comment: @Sophia : According to your screenshots, you do not have the correct MAC. Try the correct MAC (hardware Ethernet line), change 00:01:08:a3:bb:c3 to 08:00:27:47;7f:8d. You may or may not need to delete your existing leases file and the backup and re-boot, not sure.

Comment: Changing MAC has indeed solved my issue, thanks a lot!